# Android - Sliding Drawer Hang Out (Stuck Out)?

Tags: java, android, slidingdrawer

how to make the content of the sliding drawer a little "stuck out" (hang out)?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRX8K.png]

After pull

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gWvb.png]

Comment: I don't think I understand the question...

Comment: I don't believe that is possible without writing your own sliding drawer code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with the stock widget.

However, someone asked about this before and an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9976924/1105376) was posted by someone who has made a class to allow you to do just that.  Follow the answer link for instructions.

The code is [here](http://pastebin.com/FtVyrcEb)

Comment: @AIR Glad I could help.  Welcome to SO.  If this helped out you should accept it as the answer (click the check mark next to it).  If it was really helpful you could upvote it too (click the up arrow).  Accepting an answer does two things...  1) It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, so they don't need to click on it just to find out that you no longer need help  2) It gives credit (in the form of Reputation) the the person that helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to do it within your XML file

```
<SlidingDrawer

              android:id="@+id/drawer"
              android:layout_width = "320dp" //set what ever dimensions you find appopriate
              android:layout_height = "440dp"
              android:orientation = "vertical"
              android:handle="@+id/handle"
              android:content="@+id/content">

<ImageView
              android:id="@+id/handle"
              android:layout_width="48dp" // Set your dimensions. This will be your handle
              android:layout_height="48dp"
              android:src="@drawable/putHandleImageHere" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/content"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text ="Hello World" />
```

---------------EDIT------------------
I reread your question and I see that your trying to have the content hang out. Try using

```
android:paddingTop="10dp"
```

or

```
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
```

Let me know if that worked, good luck.